# startup/shutdown screen / grub changed after installing xfce

Tags: xfce, plymouth

I installed 12.04 right after release. Yesterday I tried Xfce4. First I tried to install it using

```
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

This worked, except I didn't get Xubuntu theming. So I installed `xubuntu-desktop` package.

But now my startup/shutdown screens are changed to Xubuntu style, and grub even says *debian*.

How do I revert these changes without uninstalling Xfce Xubuntu theming?

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/q/122081/43660

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in the terminal

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

You will get the following screen:

[image: reconfigure]

then enter on `OK` and you will get a screen similar to this with listings as `XDM` or `LXDM` and `LIGHTDM`

[image: configure lightdm]

scroll down the navigation to `lightdm` and press **Enter**.

You will get the Ubuntu login screen back.

Answer (score 1):

Removing desktop-base package solved the debian grub image problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove desktop-base
```

Answer (score 0):

### To revert Grub to the default Ubuntu style:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all desktop-grub
sudo update-grub
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127486&p=12567821#post12567821)

### To revert the Plymouth boot screen to the default Ubuntu style:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/147697/18665)