# After installing Xfce Desktop it changed my original theme/screen

Tags: 12.04, unity, xfce

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and recently i installed Gnome and Xfce Desktop Environment. Now I have the problem that every time I start up or shutdown Ubuntu I see numbers something about Xfce, but i do not see the loading image below:

[image: Ubuntu loading image]

My startup/shutdown screens are changed to Xubuntu style (I guess), and grub even says debian. I managed to solve the Grub problem by running this from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove desktop-base
```

But how can I bring back the original Ubuntu 12.04 startup and shutdown theme ?

---

- I tried this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130582/startup-shutdown-screen-grub-changed-after-installing-xfce) and set it to lightdm but it did not resolve my problem.
- I removed Xubuntu (Xfce) like [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntuprecise) described. But i still don't
  see the default Ubuntu startup and shutdown screen. Any more
  suggestions ?
- I also tried this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen), now it is better but it is still not the original loading image. Also the resolution is bad. The letters are too big.

Comment: I have a similar issue. For me my themes and icons in Ubuntu session are completely messed up. I expected only my xubuntu session to be different.

Comment: The accepted answer for this question covers your problem:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/460571/i-have-installed-xfce-on-ubuntu-13-10-but-now-icons-and-colors-in-unity-is-stra

Comment: @W.Goeman thanks for the comment. But I moved on to Ubuntu 14.04. As it seems the above problems are very common in Ubuntu and most of the times the Graphic card is responsible.