# I have installed xfce on ubuntu 13.10, but now icons and colors in unity is strange. How to fix?

Tags: unity, xfce

I wanted to install XUbunutu looks on my Ubuntu machine and I have done it like so:

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

But now when I have restarted the machine, I first got xUbuntu log-out scree. WHen I got back to the login screen, I got Xfce (xubuntu) login screen, and even I login to the unity, I have xfce icons set up and the colors of the menu. Like this
[image]

What I would like is to have a Ubuntu like login screen, and the ubuntu looks when I login to ubunty (unity) and not some mixed xfce-ubunty experience.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

and

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

unity --reset-icons
```

**But it didn't work**.

Can someone help me how to return the original Ubuntu looks when I get to the login screen and when I login to unity UI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What seems to have happened is that XFCE have changed some settings on your system, as such, your Ubuntu looks the way it does. You're going to have to reset some of these settings back to their defaults by running a few commands.

### Reset Icons

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'ubuntu-mono-dark'
```

### Reset Theme

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Ambiance'
```

### Reset Login Screen

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

The above will fix the looks of the unity. Next is the login screen.

### Reset Login Screen

There are two options for this:

#### First:

Run these commands:

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

Then choose your ubuntu option: `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth`

And then run: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

#### Second:

Run in terminal:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

**After running the second (or even the first option)** you will probably **NOT** see the results just yet. As those scripts are not updating all necessary files, edit the `lightdm.config` file (thanks to help of this post https://askubuntu.com/a/421322/223469):

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And change values to (previous value was probably xubuntu):

```
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Save and reset.

After those changes the login screen should appear.

All what is left to do is to return loading screen, but so far I haven't managed to do that, but will update once I find the solution

Comment: Hm, okay, I will try with that, but there are other things that are a bit different - notifications (that I haven't mentioned in he questions) and also the login screen is from xfce and I would like to return to unity. Is there a way to do that, but resting unity or something like that?

Comment: How are the notifications different? I have also included the login screen fix.

Comment: well they look just like the notifications on xubuntu - the color, position etc. For example: the notification for low disk space is displayed as a notification box right under the clock, but on Ubuntu this notification is shown as a separate window and no notification is shown. Also the login fix didn't work :/ the screen is the same as before

Comment: Can you try `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager'` to try and change the login screen?

Comment: I have tried. Nothing changed

Comment: That's very strange. It should have changed to lightdm. Have you tried restarting (although I'm not certain it'll work)

Comment: Yes, I have, and nothing has changed. I am searching the internet. Meanwhile, I have tried your icon setting and it did work, Thanks. I am just checking login and I think I will be good to go :)

Comment: Do tell me what works, so I can update the answer and have it accepted so new users or people visiting about this problem know that this works

Comment: Of course. That is why I post questions here :) I will let you know whit what to update the answer once I found the solution

Comment: Michael, I have edited the answer. If I find the last remaining thing - the loading screen, I will update, but so far it works. And even better, the notifications (e.g. disk space errors) from xubuntu are not removed, which I find interesting and looks nice, and all that with unity looks. Great side-effect :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Unity Tweak Tool?

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then launch in terminal: `unity-tweak-tool`, go to **Appearance→Icons→Ubuntu-mono-dark**, **Appearance→Theme→Ambiance** etc (Try to chose different ones and back to default like Ambiance)

### For login screen try:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

### If you have problem with boot screen try:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Chose number of: **/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth** (default)

Then: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: I have to be careful with the suggestions. It seems that with this one I would be installing a new lightdm with in essence is not the standard unity login for 13.10 as I can recall. Also adding a new tweaks seems that drives me even further from just "reseting" the old unity style login and other settings (?)

Comment: I have tried the suggestions even with `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update the login screen, but it didn't work. All stayed the same - still xubunty shown :/

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u` is for boot screen. LightDM looks like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rzOewcQH3nM/Ul_w6xnKuFI/AAAAAAAAFQ8/SiSCImqwdmw/s1000/lightdm-whitedots.jpg), it is default 13.10 login screen. You can tweak your PC far as you like