# How to make my computer start as Ubuntu not Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have computer with Ubuntu and Lubuntu. When I start the computer it shows the Lubuntu logo then goes to the Lubuntu login screen.  I want it to start the computer showing the Ubuntu logo and going to the Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: Do you have two separate OS installed, or just two desktop environments?

Comment: Just as two different desktop environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you installed Lubuntu after (upon) the Ubuntu (Unity) installation. This action has changed some things. These are:

1) The plymouth theme, was replaced by Lubuntu theme

2) The LightDM (default display manager-login screen) theme was replaced by Lubuntu-lightdm theme.(lightdm-gtk-greeter).

You will be able to restore these themes.

[How do I revert the Plymouth theme back to default ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113973/how-do-i-revert-the-plymouth-theme-back-to-default-after-purging-kubuntu)

[How to change the LightDM theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)

The default login screen for Ubuntu Unity is `greeter-session=unity-greeter`