# Getting Ubuntu's default splash screen back after KDE installation & removal

Tags: boot, kde, plymouth

I know questions similar to this one, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12394/getting-back-ubuntus-default-boot-splash?lq=1), have been asked and solved. However, I tried their answers and none of them worked.

As one of the askers of the questions did, I also tried KDE just out of curiosity, but later, I realized I had plenty with Unity, so I uninstalled it. The only thing that is left to bring my machine to normal is the splash screen.

When I installed KDE, the original Ubuntu's splash screen:

[image: Ubuntu's splash screen]

mutated to an ugly screen where I could read "Kubuntu 14.04" with red little pixels.

I have been able to remove that screen following the answers of the questions I linked above. But as a result, I have no splash screen, it goes black with a _ blinking in the upper left corner until the login screen appears.

As I said before, I have already tried the solutions of these other answers, including

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

which let's me choose between 2 options (one of them apparently duplicated): [image: plymouth], but none works. Also

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash

FRAMEBUFFER=y

$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

does not work either.

The reason why they don't work might be that, before I found these solutions, I removed with rm all files in the plymouth folder whose names started by kubuntu (`kubuntu*`). Also, I replaced the content of `/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymout` to exactly match:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Ubuntu Logo
Description=A theme that features a blank background with a logo.
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

EDIT: This is the output of the `sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
[sudo] password for antortjim:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 518027 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo_0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1) over (0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1) ...
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert the Plymouth theme](http://askubuntu.com/q/113973/295286). Among other things look up plymouth themes with `apt-cache search plymouth | less` and then install new one that you desire. the one i use is called solar or something along those lines

Comment: I found the solar theme, is it the same as the original one? Also, how do I install it? Thank you

Comment: Nope, it's a different one, but that's one i use, Ubuntu text on blue background with stars and splash of chemical reactions on the sun in the lower right corner of the screen. Pretty cool IMHO. Original is `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` i think, but don't quote me. You probably already have it so might wanna do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`

Comment: Unfortunately, that command does not work either, even if I run `sudo update-initramfs -u` after it (which I have come to think that is included in the command you proposed). I am gonna paste the output of what you proposed. Thank you again